# API display logic serverside or clientside

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, api

I'm refactoring an API where there are user profiles from a profiles table and profile images in a separate table.  Currently the API queries the profile tables, and then loops through the images table for associated image data (paths etc).  There is logic built in that adds a default img path when a profile image isn't set.  So if we are displaying 50 profiles there are 51 queries being run.

I'm considering refactoring where the initial profile query joins the image table.  I'm now left with **two options**.

1. I can loop through the results server side to build the image paths.  I will have to loop through them again client side to display the results.
2. I can loop through the results one time client side and build the image paths there.  The path logic is easy and a simple if statement.

It seems 2 would be the logical choice.  But is it?  I guess this is part of a bigger question of when you are building out APIs and the client side interfaces when do you move code from the server to the client to keep the API fast at risk of slowing down the browser?  How do you do this dance?  I'm working on another API using Node for the jquery datatables plugin where there needs to be a lot more code to marry the backend, and it's been a bit of a tug of war determining how much I should hand over to the browser.  A fast API is of not much use if you are crashing your visitors browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The tipping for the decision for me, would be
Am I by exposing parts of the component path, so the client can build it, exposing something I don't want to.

vs

Am I by constructing the image paths server side doing work that the client might not need, or that the client might have to redo, like chopping them up on occasion for instance.

In terms of passing more data than is needed, I'm not seeing an issue from what you've said, and the first question would be one with the most priority for me.

Sort of stretching in this scenario, but the client having to know how to compose the image path, sets a few constraints, whereas if it's all done server side the implementation details are hidden. Despite them being simple, that would be my default option

As you've said it's a tug of war. Another way to look at issues like this, is the "right" answer can depend on when you ask the question. You could go one way and them a bit later, some new requirement pops up, and now it's the wrong one....

Simple and consistent is the thing to aim for. Right as in best? 20/20 hindsight time.

Comment: Good point on when you are asking the question.  Does solution 2 makes sense if future proposed changes get queued up.
I think I present a good example because this is literally a simple if statement with one line in it.  It's easy to do either way, but IMO it's cleaner and DRYer to do it on the client, but it is another task for the browser to handle.

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen and done this in the past I've found it better not to store images (like what it sounds like you are doing) in a db. Put them in a place where the browser can link to them and pass the path from the server.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough I'm not storing the images themselves just the data necessary to build the image path.  The images are on Cloudfront.

Comment: I wondered. In this case I'd assume that the browser was the weakest link. Do as much as possible server-side and pass the rendering to the client. If the browser happens to be running on a stout machine then all the better. But you're worse off if you ask too much and it can't deliver. You know what your server is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.. you are displaying some sort of profiles list where each profile has associated image... right?

Abstracting from the way you store images(db or vfs images are faster but straight files - with at least minor MRU Cache - are easier to maintain).

Solution numero uno is the right way to go.

It is just simpler and more "restful". I am a huge fan of client logic, but we should use it for a good cause(such as Soopa-UI). Same goes for db logic code vs server logic code. I dislike sql and having to maintain another layer of problems, but I do understand the difference it makes in some cases to the final result.

EDIT: Oh... you are storing just paths.
So if you are not doing some fancy one page web app then there is another problem with building paths client side. Client would have to wait for script to finish loading before his images would even start to load.